# Connected to Database yet unable to perform operations

Tags: java, sql-server, database, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to access the SQL server database from my application. The connection is successful from my connection factory class, but for some reason, the JDBC query that I am firing for login is unable to fetch any details. The SQL Server is installed in the local machine and all users and databases are present. All dependent libraries have been successfully imported and placed inside the WEB-INF/lib folder for access by the web application. (Basically there are no dependencies externally.) I have tested the query that I am using inside the Login servlet from the front end using SQL Server Management Studio and it is fetching details correctly. I am unable to understand where the query is failing to work.

Following is the code for the connection factory class.

```
package com.util;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    static String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Portal";
    static String uname="Portal";
    static String pass="portal_1";
    static String driverclass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

    private ConnectionFactory(){

    }

    public static Connection getConn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName(driverclass);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I am using this class to create and return a connection object wherever there is a requirement to connect to the database.

The following is the login module which is a servlet that I am using to perform the operation of login when the user clicks login in the index page after entering credentials.

```
import com.util.CommonOps;
import com.util.ConnectionFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Login() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession sess = request.getSession();

    String uname = (String) request.getParameter("uname");
    String pass = (String) request.getParameter("pass");

    // System.out.println(pass);
    uname = CommonOps.sanitzeData(uname);
    pass = CommonOps.sanitzeData(pass);

    // System.out.println(pass);

    // Username can be in any case.can It will take the upper case value by
    // default.

    uname = uname.toUpperCase();
    uname = uname.trim();

    if (uname == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        sess.setAttribute("msg", "Invalid Username or Password");
    } else if (pass == null) {
        sess.setAttribute("msg", "Invalid Username or Password");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        String pass_hash = CommonOps.getHash(pass);

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            // System.out.println("Inside Try block");
            conn = ConnectionFactory.getConn();
            if(conn == null){
                System.out.println("Connection Failed");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Connection Successful");
            }
            System.out.println(conn);
            try {
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                try {

                    System.out.println(uname);
                    System.out.println(pass_hash);

                    sql = "select lg_uname, lg_pwd, lg_u_role from login where lg_uname='"
                                    + uname
                                    + "' and lg_pwd='"
                                    + pass_hash
                                    + "' "
                                    + "and lg_del_flg='N'"
                                    + "and lg_entity_cre_flg='Y'";

                    System.out.println(sql);

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                    if (rs.next()) {

                        sess.setAttribute("uname", uname);
                        String role = rs.getString(3);
                        sess.setAttribute("role", role);

                        response.sendRedirect("redirect_home.jsp");

                    } else {
                        // System.out.println("Outside while block");
                        sess.setAttribute("msg",
                                "Invalid Username or Password");
                        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                    }
                } catch (SQLSyntaxErrorException sql) {
                    sess.setAttribute("msg", "Invalid Username or Password");
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (rs != null)
                        rs.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error when closing result set");
            } finally {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error when closing statement");
        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error when closing connection");
                }
        }

    }
}
}
```

I have inserted some print statements so as to check whether connection is being established and whether valid data are being passed to the servlet and in sequence the Database.

Following is the Stack Trace of the error that I get when I hit the login button.

```
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;E:\app\IAS_Admin\product\11.2.0\client_1;E:\app\IAS_Admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\oracle\oraclient\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.7\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;E:\oracle\oraclient\orb\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\StaffPortalWork\Software\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StaffPortalMasterTemplate' did not find a matching property.
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8020
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 375 ms
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8020
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Dec 8, 2016 11:51:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 332 ms
Inside Try block
Connection successful
ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 2ce17bbd-c66d-4461-9276-e23302f4d8ba
ADMIN1
5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d
select lg_uname, lg_pwd, lg_u_role from dbo.login where lg_uname='ADMIN1' and lg_pwd='5058f1af8388633f609cadb75a75dc9d' and lg_del_flg='N'and lg_entity_cre_flg='Y'
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:800)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
    at com.serv.Login.doPost(Login.java:116)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am working with Eclipse Indigo IDE with JDK version 1.6 having the same target runtime. I am using Apache Tomcat version 6 as the application server of choice for deployment. With that I am using an express edition of MSSQL Server 2008 as database. Along with that the operating system is Microsoft Server 2008. All are in 32 bit version.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit 09/12/2016 (DD/MM/YYYY):
As requested this is the error statement after removing the print stack traces. It is throwing the error in the section where I am trying to close the statement in the try catch block.

```
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;E:\app\IAS_Admin\product\11.2.0\client_1;E:\app\IAS_Admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\oracle\oraclient\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.7\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;E:\oracle\oraclient\orb\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\StaffPortalWork\Software\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to     'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StaffPortalMasterTemplate' did not find a matching property.
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8020
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 553 ms
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:56 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8020
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:56 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:56 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/25  config=null
Dec 9, 2016 8:27:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 519 ms
Error when closing statement
```

Comment: can you execute any statements if you connect to the db other than java?

Comment: Haven't tried it, and don't have an option to try that as well. The thing is it was working fine on my local machine, now as I moved it to testing server it is facing this issue.

Comment: can you switch every e.printStackTrace() and system.out.println() in you catch blocks and run it again? i can't see where exactly the error occurs

Comment: Unfortunately that could only be done tomorrow at work.

Answer (score -1):

In the SQL, you are missing a space at " lg_del_flg='N'and " that will probably make you query fail. And everything else follows...

Comment: nope that works totally fine. just tested a query with a missing space and no error

Comment: No it wont. I told you I tested it from front end, and as I replied to @XtremeBaumer I have already tested it in my local machine. Space is not the issue.